# Splunk Indexing and Space Usage

Tags: splunk

I am new to Splunk and I have download the Enterprise trial.  It permits free usage for 500MB of daily indexed data.  How do I determine my consumption of this limit?

Answer (score 2):

Splunk will tell you.  Go to Settings->Monitoring Console->Indexing->License Usage.